# Calling Node Native Addons (C++) in Electron

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I'm completely new to Node JS and Electron. I'm trying to integrate C++ with HTML using Electron and Node JS. I have went through some examples given by: [GIT](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples)

What i'm trying to do is calling the native function (hello()) from my web page's javascript which is loaded by electron. I have used `node-gyp configure` to generate my Visual Studio Solution File. (**.sln**). And later i compiled my code with Visual Studio 2013 Express which successfully generate my **.node** file in build\Release Folder.

This is my index.js file:

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/hello.node');
console.log(addon.hello());
```

when I simply run this with `node index.js`, it is giving me the desired output:

```
world
```

But the problem comes with when i Use Electron. I'm using electron binary (32 bit) to run my webpage.

The following is my **main.js** file:

```
var app = require('app');  // Module to control application life.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');  // Module to create native browser window.


require('crash-reporter').start();

var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1366, height: 768});
    mainWindow.loadUrl("file://" + __dirname + "/HtmlFile/index.html");
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

Now this is my javascript where i'm calling the native addon:

```
//************* My Functional logic **************
 //************************************************

var addon = require('../build/Release/hello');
alert(addon.hello());
```

When i run this or load this page, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:137
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyAPP\build\Release\hello.node
```

Following is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "MyAPP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Desc",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nan": "^2.0.9"
  },
  "gypfile": true
}
```

This is my `binding.gyp`:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue when using the `--arch=ia32` flag. When I use the `--arch=x64` flag I receive `Uncaught Error: The system cannot find message text for message number 0x%1 in the message file for %2.` However, if I run the command with `node ./` it prints out "world" to the command line as expected. Also the same code works on MacOS in electron, so appears to be a Windows electron based issue.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may not have the correct binary configured. Sorry not sure if this will work for the native module, but you could try [rebuilding](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#the-easy-way)...

**Note:** Please insure you have the correct arguments for your node-gyp command (if that is how you will rebuild).

- `--target=<your electron version>`
- `--target_platform=win32` (Not in the example link, but you seem to be using windows)
- `--arch=<your architecture>` (x64 = 64bit, x86 = 32bit)

Comment: I haven't found any such directory structure in my development environment. I'm using only electron binary to run my app.

Comment: My bad. I shouldn't try to read questions at 3am. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments I was running into this same issue. To resolve it you need to add a couple additional flags:

```
node-gyp rebuild --target=<your electron version> --arch=<insert your arch> --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
```

This will get the proper requirements from the atom.io site and build the add-on correctly. For more information you can checkout electron's specific [docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.34.0/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/) on using native modules.

Answer (score 1):

using node-gyp directly will build with nodejs headers, but electron has different headers.

first you should figure out witch electron version electron is using.
you can write a js like this

```
console.log(process.version);
```

use electron to execute this script,my version is 0.36.1
and change directory to the module you want to build

```
#On Windows Try this
cd /path-to-module/
npm install bindings nan node-gyp
node-gyp rebuild --target=0.36.1 --arch=x64 --dist-    url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell
#notice the target version is the electron binary version
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal problem regarding node vs electron headers in native addons required a different dist-url parameter value:

```
 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron
```

Hope it will help someone.

PS: Still cannot figure out how to set it using .npmrc in windows (

Comment: Put this in your .npmrc in your project root folder

```runtime = electron \n
target_arch = x64/x86 \n
target = 1.7.9 <target version> \n
disturl = https://atom.io/download/atom-shell \n
progress = true```

Comment: @niketan, but then how I would build for the alternate architecture? Change the file every time?